# How to fix error with numpy while installing TA-Lib in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ta-lib

I am using Google Colab and the installation and import of TA-Lib has stopped working. I previously had problems installing the package in Google Colabs, which I resolved with the following:

```
!wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
%cd ta-lib/
!./configure --prefix=/usr
!make
!make install
!pip install Ta-Lib
import talib
```

But recently this stopped working. it gives me the following error:

```
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-2-e564c1928385> in <cell line: 8>()
> 6 get_ipython().system('make install')
> 7 get_ipython().system('pip install Ta-Lib')
> 8 import talib
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/talib/__init__.py in <module>
> 91 
> 92 
> 93 from ._ta_lib import (
> 94     _ta_initialize, _ta_shutdown, MA_Type, __ta_version__,
> 95     _ta_set_unstable_period as set_unstable_period,
> 
> talib/_func.pxi in init talib._ta_lib()
> 
> __init__.pxd in numpy.import_array()
> 
> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
> 
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
> manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the "Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i it's related to the numpy version installed in colab.

I resolved it with

```
!pip install numpy==1.23.0 --force
```

after that restart the run time, clicking on the outputed link by colab

and run

```
import numpy
numpy.__version__
```

to validate it was sucessfully installed.

With version 1.23 of numpy you can now import talib again with no problem.